# IQ test problem - 3x3 grid with colours

Tags: visual, pattern, progressive-matrix

This problem is from iqzilla2 on brainzilla.com (https://www.brainzilla.com/iq-tests/iqzilla-2/) What is the answer and why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is

> G

just like the other two answers. I think that the explanation is the following however:

> there are three tiles, they are green, brown and grey. When they coincide, we see a yellow square. Each of these three appears once at each of the nine possible positions. In the eight shown configurations, brown appears everywhere except at the bottom right, green everywhere except for the bottom middle, and grey everywhere except for the bottom left, so the missing piece is G.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>*This is currently a partial answer. Nonetheless, I have discovered some useful information, including the correct solution the puzzle.*</sub>

---

The correct answer is:

> **G**

A core concept of this puzzle:

> Tiles can overlap and hide each other.

Further Reasoning:

> First, look at the red tile. Wherever it is visible, it takes the square in the mini grid that matches the mini grid's position in the larger 3*3 grid. (This is similar to puzzle $1$ of the linked IQ test.) Whenever it is not visible, the yellow tile is in that position. This causes me to believe that the yellow tile is effectively hiding the red on in these cases.

> Next, the green tile. The first thing I noticed was that it generally followed a diagonal path of motion from one tile to the next, moving down and to the left, wrapping around the board as it goes. The only time it doesn't do this is from the fourth grid to the fifth. In this case, it simply moves over from one side of the grid to the other, maintaining the same horizontal row as it does. Then I realized that this horizontal motion could also occur between the first and second grid tiles, if I considered the fact that, yet again, the yellow tile was hiding it. The same logic also holds between the seventh and eighth grids.

Using this information:

> The red tile's move logic would have it being placed in the lower-right corner of the grid where the question mark is. The green tile would be in the lower center of the grid if its logic is followed. The only answer that fulfills both of these criteria is answer **G**. (It turns out, you can check this to be the case by choosing that answer and clicking to finish the IQ test. Your results come back as a 1/30, meaning that you answered correctly.)

What I don't know:

> I don't know the move logic for either the Grey or Yellow tiles, but was still able to solve it by deduction. I also don't necessarily know which tiles can hide other tiles.

***Thanks for reading! : )***

Answer (score 0):

> like the answer above there are some rules about colours showing on overlaps that I don't fully understand.

> imagine the smaller squares are numbered one to nine from left to right and top to bottom in each grid.

> yellow + red both start at 1 and are +1 for each following grid (I'm not sure why on some grids the yellow shows and sometimes the red)

> green starts at 1 and is +2 on each subsequent grid, (this loops around on the 6th grid)

> I'm not sure exactly what is going on with the grey tile - It seems to be +4 in many cases, except for when it's in the 3rd position and it seems to reflect to the 7th position (corner to corner, this happens in the 1st and 8th grid). This doesn't feel like a good solution for the Grey though.

> this would suggest G is indeed the answer.

Comment: What about the seventh grid? Yellow is in space 5, so it must have some sort of alternate logic.

Comment: Oh I missed that, well spotted, I’m not sure what is going on there

Comment: It's all good. I have no idea what it should be, either.